# Stripes & checkerboard pattern on MacBook Pro monitor

Tags: hardware, display

I am trying to fix a MacBook Pro (one of the earliest Intel processor models) that spontaneously gets into a state where stripes would appear in a checkerboard pattern all over the display. Please see attached image:

[image]

I can't find anything trigger for this phenomenon, occasionally it appears during the startup process when the grey Apple logo appears.

When it occurs, the display is frozen and I can't do any work. However, the computer itself seems to still function, because I can press then power button followed by Return, and the computer will turn off.

I suspect this is a hardware problem, one that is hard to fix because this model is so old with no warranty for years. But I would appreciate any ideas on how I may fix it before I give up. Thank you.

Comment: I actually had this exact same problem with a PC laptop once. Turned out to be the LCD cable that went between the lid and the computer was starting to fray from rubbing inside the hing.

Comment: @vcjones Thanks for your comment. Can anyone else confirm that this might be the case for this MacBook Pro? If so, I'll probably have to part with it and move on...